# Javascript split dictionary data with multiple keys

Tags: javascript

I have some dictionary data that have multiple keys.
I want to turn it to a submenu but the number of keys are different.
here is the flattened data

```
const input = {
    "rule.id": "id",
    "rule.ruleset": ["rule1", "rule2"],
    "severity": "error",
    "source.as.number": 32,
    "source.as.organization.name": "My Organization",
    "source.bytes": 4534,
    "source.geo.city_name": "Berlin",
    "source.geo.location.lat": 49.23,
    "source.geo.location.lon": 50.34,
    "destination.geo.location.lat": 23.34,
    "destination.geo.location.lon": 49.34,
};
```

I got the keys:

```
var keys = [];
for (var key in input) {
    if (input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        keys.push(key);
    }
}
console.log(keys)
```

And my output looks like this:

```
[
  'rule.id',
  'rule.ruleset',
  'severity',
  'source.as.number',
  'source.as.organization.name',
  'source.bytes',
  'source.geo.city_name',
  'source.geo.location.lat',
  'source.geo.location.lon',
  'destination.geo.location.lat',
  'destination.geo.location.lon'
]
```

I tried to get keys separated after "." After that I'll make a submenu with using these keys. Here is one thing that I wonder. I flattened my dictionary data but now i'am not sure it is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

Here one possible solution with some sample data to show the implementation works.

```js
const input = {
  "rule.id": "id",
  "rule.ruleset": ["rule1", "rule2"],
  "severity": "error",
  "source.as.number": 32,
  "source.as.organization.name": "My Organization",
  "source.bytes": 4534,
  "source.geo.city_name": "Berlin",
  "source.geo.location.lat": 49.23,
  "source.geo.location.lon": 50.34,
  "destination.geo.location.lat": 23.34,
  "destination.geo.location.lon": 49.34,
};

/**
 * Sets a value at a given path
 * @param {Object} obj object to set the value
 * @param {string} path path at which to set the value
 * @param {any} value value to set
 * @returns object with value set a specified path
 */
function setValue(obj, path, value){
    let cur = obj;
    const props = path.split(".")
    for (let index = 0; index < props.length - 1; index++) {
        const prop = props[index];
        if(!cur[prop]) cur[prop] = {};
        cur = cur[prop]; 
    }
    cur[props[props.length - 1]] = value;
    return obj;
}

const output = Object.entries(input).reduce((obj, [path, value]) => setValue(obj, path, value), {})
console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Explanation

We first need to obtain the paths and values using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and the we can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to loop over those. We start of with an empty object `{}` and then for each `path`-`value` pair we set the value at the given path.

To do this we need the function `setValue()` which sets a value at a specified path. First, we need to [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the path to get the parts of a path. Then we loop over the partial paths until the second to last part. Then everytime we encounter an `undefined` property we set that property to `{}`. Then we need to set the current object (variable `cur`) to that new property, so we can do the same in the next iteration.

For the last part of the path, which we left out in the previous `for` loop, we can know simply set the value.

#### Display menu

If you wanted to show the result in a nested list as is often used for menus like this, you could use something like the following.

This uses React, but you could map something like this to vanilla JS or whatever framework you are using:

```js
const toDisplay = {
  rule: {
    id: "id",
    ruleset: ["rule1", "rule2"],
  },
  severity: "error",
  source: {
    as: {
      number: 32,
      organization: {
        name: "My Organization",
      },
    },
    bytes: 4534,
    geo: {
      city_name: "Berlin",
      location: {
        lat: 49.23,
        lon: 50.34,
      },
    },
  },
  destination: {
    geo: {
      location: {
        lat: 23.34,
        lon: 49.34,
      },
    },
  },
};

const isObject = (obj) =>
  typeof obj === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj) && obj !== null;

function showObject(obj) {
  if (isObject(obj))
    return Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => (
      <li>
        {key}
        <ul>{showObject(value)}</ul>
      </li>
    ));
  else if (Array.isArray(obj)) return obj.map((item) => <li>{showObject(item)}</li>);
  return <li>{obj}</li>;
}

function App() {
  return <ul>{showObject(toDisplay)}</ul>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```